# Маркеры в OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, openstreetmap

Коллеги, может быть кто-то сталкивался. Есть android-приложение, в одном из фрагментов я разместил карту с помощью osmdroid. На карте поллиниями рисуются маршруты и на нужных точках стоят стандартные маркеры. Каким образом можно заменить стандартный маркер на свой, и чтобы для каждой точки он был разным? В идеале в виде цифр: 1, 2, 3...  т.д. Чтобы соответствовало порядку маршрута.